# Sort a table in JQuery by a column that has version information

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I have a table that has among other fields, a column that shows versions. This means the value 1.1 is different to 1.10 but as a number they are the same, 1.1 = 1.10

So, I need to separate the numbers on both sides of the point and sort them. for.e.g:
Current sort:

```
1.1
1.10
1.11
1.2
```

The sort I am looking for is :

```
1.1
1.2
1.10
1.11
```

I am using HTML5, Bootstrap, JQuery, MVC
I use Ajax calls to get the data from web API. Then create the table dynamically.

```
var str = '<br/><table id="tblBuildsGrid" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-nowrap hover order-column text-center" style="word-wrap: break-word !important;">';
str += '<thead id="buildsGridTableHeader" class="text-center overlayMainHeader"><tr>';
str += '<th style="width: 34px !important;" class="no-sort glyphicon-column sorting_disabled"></th>';
str += '<th class="text-center" id="buildVersionSortedColumn">Build Version</th>';
str += '<th class="text-center">Owner</th>';
str += '<th class="text-center">Build Type</th>';
str += '<th class="text-center">Effective Date</th>';
str += '<th class="text-center">Product</th>';
str += '<th class="text-center">Status</th>';
str += '<th class="hide"></th>';
str += '<th class="hide"></th>';
str += '<th class="hide"></th>';
str += '<th class="hide"></th>';
str += '<th class="hide"></th>';
str += '<th class="hide"></th>';
str += '<th class="hide"></th>';
str += '<th class="hide"></th>';

str += '</tr></thead>';

str += '<tbody>';
```

Please help.

Comment: You need to implement your own `sort()` functionality. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rory, for the quick response.

I found a solution to this problem by fixing this in the repository. I pad a zero for the version if the digits are single.